# What is the speed of a swimmer in a river when he wants to travel the minimum distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

The speed of the swimmer in still water is $v$ and that of the river is $u$ ($v>u$). He should travel at an angle $x$ with respect to the direction perpendicular to the river's flow, towards the direction opposite to river's flow.

Therefore, for minimum distance, $v\sin x=u. $

Hence, the velocity of the swimmer would be equal to $$v\cos x= \sqrt{v^2 - u^2}.$$

But if we use vectors and find the resultant of $v$ & $u$, we would get
$$ \sqrt{v^2 + u^2 +2vu\cos[90+x]}= \sqrt{v^2 + u^2 -2vu\sin x}$$

So, shouldn't 
$$\sqrt{v^2 + u^2 -2vu\sin x}$$
be the speed of the man instead of $$\sqrt{v^2 - u^2}$$ as velocity of man is the resultant of the velocity of river and velocity of man in still water?

[image]

Comment: No, you are taking the wrong angle. x is the angle between the velocity of the swimmer in still water and the direction perpendicular to the river's flow. I think you are taking the angle between the river's bank and the swimmer's velocity in still water.

Comment: Got it. Anyway, nothing is wrong with your approach. For finding the minimum distance, we just know that the horizontal component of the velocity have to be equal to the rivers flow (only then will the swimmer move along a straight line perpendicular to the river's flow). That's just a way to get through the problem. In this manner, you wont have to know the value of $x$ to get the resultant. You just know that the swimmer will have to move like that. To get the resultant through the typical formula you will need more info, which is actually not necessary to obtain.

Comment: minimum distance to where ... the opposite bank of the river?

Comment: Yes, David. Minimum distance to the opposite bank, which would be perpendicular to the river's flow.

Comment: FYI: If you want to do the least _work_ swimming across a river and/or spend the least amount of time in the water, then you don't want to minimize the length of your path over the ground. You want to minimize the length of your path through the moving water. Swim directly toward the opposite shore, and don't mind the fact that the current carries you down stream as you go. (If there's some hazard downstream of you that you want to avoid, then start by walking upstream far enough that you won't be carried into it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct and the resultant velocity should be which is the same as our result before as I'll clarify:
$$v_R=\sqrt{v^2-u^2}$$
You have to understand that you do not *need* to use the angle $x$ because look at this diagram:[image]

Then if we substitute $sin(x)=\frac{u}{v}$ into this:
$$v_R=\sqrt{v^2 + u^2 -2vu\sin x}$$
Then it becomes
$$v_R=\sqrt{v^2 + u^2 -2vu*\frac{u}{v}}$$
$$v_R=\sqrt{v^2 + u^2 -2u^2}$$
Which then becomes the original result of:
$$v_R=\sqrt{v^2-u^2}$$
It's just a matter of using Pythagoras theorem here when trigonometry is unnecessary.